# Android: Fragments, popBackStack method goes too back

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I learned that popBackStack method cancels the operation defined with the addToBackStack method.

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragment2 = BlankFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2", "");
            listaFragment2.add(fragment2);
            i++;
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linearLayout, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("myfrag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            //viene salvata l'AZIONE che si COMPIE E BASTA, ovvero quella di aggiungere il fragment2, in caso si volesse annullare questa
            //operazione per far scomparire SOLO IL FRAGMENT2

        }
    });
findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //si annulla l'operazione a cui il popStack è legato, ovvero si annulla l'operazione di aggiungere il fragment 2
            //una volta annullato, non si può ripetere il popoBackStack se non è stato precedentemente annunciato
            fragmentManager.popBackStack("myfrag",1);
        }
    });
```

When I click the button, I add the fragment number 2, so if I click 5 times the button, I add 5 fragments number 2. When I click the button4, I want to remove only the last operation(defined in the OnClickListener of the R.id.button), so if I click the button 5 times and then I click the button4, **I want to remove only the fifth fragment2, because in theory adding the fifth fragment2 is the last operation!** But if I click the button4, I remove all fragments2. **Does the method addToBackStack override and cancel the previous method (that method which adds the fourth fragment2) or "add itself" to the previous one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have named all of your backstacks "myfrag", so it is popping all of your backstacks.

Either use `i` to generate a `myFrag1`, `myFrag2` and so on, or do not use a name in `popBackStack`:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```